# Mean and SD for distance between occurrences of a given value in sequence drawn at random

Tags: distributions, mean

Given an infinite sequence of values, selected at random (with replacement) from a set of N values, I choose some value X from the set of values.  Then, starting from the first occurrence of X in the sequence, I count the number of values between each subsequent occurrence of X, giving a new sequence.  What is the mean and SD of this new sequence?

For example, if N=2 and the values are 0 and 1, my infinite sequence might start:

```
0010101101111000101010011001001...
```

if I choose X to be 1 then the new sequence is:

```
0010101101111000101010011001001...
    1 10 1000   3 1 1  20  2  2...
```

or the number of 0s that separates each successive 1.

Thanks.

[I expected this to have a mean and variance of N (vaguely remembering something about Poisson stats from school), but some experimenting seems to suggest the SD is N.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean the number of draws until $X$ occurs again. The probability distribution is the geometric distribution.  The probability that after $X$ occurs it will occur again on the next draw is $p=1/N$.  So Let $k= \text{number of draws until the next } $X$ \text{ is drawn}$.  For any $k\geq 1$ the probability that the random variable $M=k$ is $(1-p)^{k-1} p$ for $k=1,2,3,...,\infty$, where $p=1/N$.  The reason is that each draw is independent and for $M$ to be equal to $k$, the first $k-1$ draws must be different from $X$ and $X$ must occur on the $k$th draw.  So the mean is $m = \sum k p^{k-1} p$ and the variance is $\sum(k-m)^2 p^{k-1} p$. It is known that $m=1/p=N$ and the variance is $(1-p)/p^2$ and the standard deviation = $\sqrt{1-p}/p=\sqrt{(N-1)N}$

Comment: +1 but this would be easier to read if you used LaTeX

Comment: this can't be right.  the sd is ~1/N.  so a larger set of data will have a smaller spread.  isn't that obviously incorrect?

Comment: I don't know where the error crept in, but the very last formula is incorrect (rewriting the standard error in terms of $N$). It should be $\sqrt{N(N-1)}$, which is approximately $N$.

Comment: @Aniko - do you know that from elsewhere, because it doesn't follow from (1-p)/p^2 (which implies variance ~N)?

Comment: Aniko is right I made an algebraic error in the last step as 1/(1/N)=N not 1/N. My answer doesn't make sense because it goes to zero asymptotically whereas it should increase with N.  I made the correction. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelChernick but then (at least) the derivation is still wrong. you say the variance is (1-p)/p^2.  that is approx N.  if the variance is approx N how can the SD be approx N?  is no-one reading my comments here?  even the parens don't match in the final result!

Comment: @andrew-cooke - Why do you say that $(1-p)/p^2$ is approximately $N$? It is approximately $1/p^2\approx N^2$.

Comment: oh!  ok, sorry - now everything makes a lot more sense.  i had magnitudes muddled up.  i can't seem to edit the last paren though (edits need to be > 6 chars).

Comment: I did need to get rid of the last right parenthesis.  I didn't realize I left it in when I edited it.  @Aniko: He said the standard deviation was approx N not the variance. He was just repeating your original comment and incorrectly attributing it to me. You were clearly right and I very much appreciate that you caught my error.

Comment: @Henry  Some nice person put it in LaTex for me and then I edited it to make the correction.